# No Wi-Fi Adapter Found and related problems

Tags: wireless, git

I just installed Ubuntu 18.04 on a brand new laptop. When trying to connect to Wi-Fi I get the error message:

*No Wi-Fi Adapter Found*

I have successfully tethered my android to the laptop so I have Internet access.

The first part of the existing advise online is to

```
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
```

But this just gives me the error message

```
 Command 'git' not found, but can be installed with
sudo apt install git
```

But this just gives me the error message

```
 myname@myname-Legion-Y540-17IRH:~$ sudo apt install git [sudo]
 password for myname:  Reading package lists... Done Building
 dependency tree        Reading state information... Done Some packages
 could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested an
 impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution
 that some required packages have not yet been created or been moved
 out of Incoming. The following information may help to resolve the
 situation:

 The following packages have unmet dependencies:  git : Depends:
 liberror-perl but it is not installable E: Unable to correct problems,
 you have held broken packages.
```

Now what do I do?

Sorry if I'm missing something obvious. I don't code, nor do I work much in the terminal.

EDIT:

> sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade

was completed without any error messages. But when rebooting the computer, Ubuntu would not start. Instead, after the Lenovo screen but before the Ubuntu screen, I get stuck at a black screen with a horizontal greenish line at the top of the screen. At this point I could only force the computer to shut down with the power button. Then I booted from a USB, erased the drive and re-installed Ubuntu. Then I tried it again and exactly the same thing happened again. So now I installed Ubuntu three times.

And as requested, here's the output:

> myname@myname-Legion-Y540-17IRH:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list
>   00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9560
>   [Jefferson Peak] [8086:a370] (rev 10)     Subsystem: Intel Corporation
>   Device [8086:0034]    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi   Kernel modules:
>   iwlwifi 0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN     Soft blocked: no    Hard blocked:
>   yes 1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth   Soft blocked: yes   Hard blocked:
>   yes 2: hci0: Bluetooth    Soft blocked: yes   Hard blocked: no 3: phy0:
>   Wireless LAN  Soft blocked: no    Hard blocked: no

Thank you!

Comment: You don't need any `git`, etc now. Connect to the Internet and upgrade the system by `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`. If you installed a 18.04.3 image, all driver problems will be solved.

Comment: lease [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command. Maybe your wireless adapter is not Realtek,

Comment: Found the answer from Jeremy on https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2415845